# FileName of fileupload is empty after a partial postback of an updatepanel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a FileUpload in the Updatepanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="SaveButton" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
<cc1:TabContainer CssClass="visoft__tab_xpie7" runat="server" ID="tab" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px">
 <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="اطلاعات پایه" ID="TabPanel1">
     <ContentTemplate>
      <div class="row">
       <span style="width: 100px" class="rowtitle">تصویر </span>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="ImageFileUpload" runat="server"/>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="RemoveImageButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <span style="width: 100px" class="rowtitle">Category</span>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="CategoryDropDownList" runat="server" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CategoryDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" />
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CategoryRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CategoryDropDownList" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Save" ErrorMessage="مجموعه را انتخاب کنید." Text="*" />
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="height: 300px">
       <span style="width: 100px" class="rowtitle">توضیحات کامل</span>
       <editor:HtmlEditor Style="float: left" runat="server" Width="600px" ID="DescriptionHtmlEditor" />
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Text="*" ID="DescriptionRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DescriptionHtmlEditor" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Save" ErrorMessage="توضیحات را وارد کنید ." />
       </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
    </cc1:TabPanel>
   </cc1:TabContainer> 
   <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
    <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" class="button" Width="100px" OnClick="SaveButton_Click" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Save" Text="ذخیره" />
   </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

when i was trying to access the FileUpload FileName property after a partial postback of an updatepanel, it was empty.

I want get Filenme of uploadpanel in oncange event witj javascrip, but i don't get Fullpath of file.

```
 function FileChange()
   {
    var filename = document.getElementById('<%= FileNameUpload.ClientID  %>');
    var file = document.getElementById('fileupload');
    filename.value = file.value;
   }
```

How to get filename of fileupload after partial postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i was trying to access the FileUpload FileName property after a
>   partial postback of an updatepanel, it was empty.

Update Panels simply intercept the regular form submit and perform a **FULL postback** using an xmlhttp request. Because of this, the selection initially made on the `input:file` element was already submitted in the initial postback and you can't read it anymore afterwards. To prove what I am saying, try and read the file name on the initial postback and you'll see that you'll be able to.

Looking at your code, it also seems that you are trying to set the value of `fileupload` element programmatically. This is not possible either for security reasons - you can't access a user's hard drive from Javascript and decide which file the user should upload to your website. Once the user selected the file and the form was submitted, the selection is gone; the user would have to re-select the file himself.

You can try many hacks to make this work with UpdatePanels, but the cleanest in the long run is to implement this using jQuery Ajax because you have complete control of what gets submitted and what doesn't and when.

I hope this helps clarifying why your approach won't work.